# merge colums with numbers and strings in R

Tags: r, date, merge, col

I have 3 different datasets, in two of them, there are columns "day", "month" and "year" like `1`,`January` and `2016` and in the third one there is the column "date" like `1-1-2016`. I want to merge the 3 columns in the two datasets into a new one `date` column like the third dataset so as I can merge the 3 datasets into one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the the columns and convert to a date:

```
df$date <- as.Date( paste( df$day, df$month, df$year , sep = "-" ) , format = "%d-%m-%Y" )
```

From the tidyr package:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% unite( col = date, day, month, year, sep = "-")
```

Comment: nice!! later use the `join_all()` from `plyr` package to merge at a go

Comment: I tried df <- df %>% unite( col = date, day, month, year, sep = "-")
and now a new column "date" appears like January-1-2016. But I want to convert it in form 1-1-2016. I tried df$date <- strftime(df$date, format = "%B-%d-%Y") but an error appeared "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Try using `as.Date(df$date, format = "%B-%d-%Y")` and then convert it.